# Fast linear regression in 4D array

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a 4D array of dimensions `[6,89,384,384]` corresponding to `[v,z,y,x]`. I now wish to perform a linear regression in v at each `[z,y,x]`, i.e. `linear-reg([:,z,y,x])` and save the slope to a new array. What is the fastest way to do this?

I've tried `scipy.stats.linregress` and `np.polyfit`. Both of which takes about 3 min. to complete.
Below is my current implementation.

```py
x_linfit = np.linspace(0,10,6)
for z in range(z_dim):
    for y in range(y_dim):
        for x in range(x_dim):
            data = data_frames[:,z,y,x]
            tmp_linfit = np.polyfit(x_linfit,data, deg=1)
            data_fit[z,x,y] = tmp_linfit[0]
```

Could this be done in a more clever way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Statistical regression on multi-dimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984035/statistical-regression-on-multi-dimensional-data)

Comment: I do not see how the referenced question could solve my issue. Could you present a code snippet?